# How can i check conflict in date time

Tags: c#

How could i know if there's a conflict , example i have here 
User Start time 7:00 AM End time 12:00 PM. Now if i add new Entry it should always CHECK the time. It shouldn't be the same with the first one. Meaning to say his time should be 12:00 PM Onwards. If his time is between 7-12. Example 11:00 AM this is CONFLICT since the first one has already workd in that time.

To be more clear
First entry .7:00 Am-12:00pm
Second entry 12:00pm-3pm
Third entry 3:00pm-7:00pm
And so on.
Thank you to those who will help.

Comment: Check that neither the start time nor the end time of the second entry falls between the start and end times of the first entry.

Comment: Is there any code or data you can share that indicates what you've tried? We wouldn't want to waste our time suggesting something you've already done that didn't work for you. At least being able to show how your data are structured would be a good step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do some checks on the three dates you are using.  You should make an object for this but here is a simple code section of what it should look like.

```
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        var end = start.AddHours(3);
        var newStart1 = start.AddHours(2);
        if(newStart1> start && end<= newStart1)
        {
            //valid time
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid start time.");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks i got an idea :D.